# Express route return instead of res.send()?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, router

Is it possible to return the value required for `res.send()` inside a route?

As opposed to specifically call `res.send(value)` in the route?

I tried this, and created a middleware at the end of the chain that will call `res.send()`, but apparently it never reaches it. Also, even if it did, how can I get the return value from the prev route to put it inside send() ?

Comment: [Nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers) uses express and do that, so it's possible. Your code never reaches last middleware, because you have to call next in middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work

Function:

```
function handler(callback) {
  return (req, res) => {
    res.json(callback(req, res))
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
app.get('/', handler((req, res) => {
  return { test: 1 }
})
```